# Is the vertical bar (|) valid CSS, or Firefox-specific?

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors

I noticed this rule in Firebug:

```
*|*:link {
  color:#0000EE;
}
```

I'm not sure that I've ever seen the vertical bar (`|`) before. It's in the about:PreferenceStyleSheet so it may be Firefox-specific.

What does it mean? Any link to a reference? I thought possibly that the vertical bar was an "OR", but that's the comma in CSS.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `|` selector is the [namespace selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#univnmsp). The part before the `|` is the namespace and the part after the `|` the selector.

So `*|*:link` means to match any element in any namespace that is a link.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that I haven't really noticed it before, and if you try googling "css vertical bar", good luck finding the reference although maybe I should have used the site: operator to limit to w3.org. Thx!