# What is correct syntax for using vertical bar in CSS?

Tags: css, properties

I didn't write this CSS and I don't know what to do with this code.

```
#r_constraint{
float:left;
height:40px;
| height:42px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 27px;
width:698px;
```

I'm getting an error on this property "**| height:42px;**".

```
Warning: Expected declaration but found '|'. Skipped to next declaration.
```

I looked [stackoverflow - what does pipe mean...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497934/what-does-a-pipe-do-in-a-css-selector)  but wasn't really what I was looking for.  So I tried [6.1.1. Type selectors and namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#typenmsp), but it appears to be describing using the vertical bar for elements, just like here [is-the-vertical-bar-valid-css-or-firefox-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421468/is-the-vertical-bar-valid-css-or-firefox-specific).  And at [4. CSS Qualified names](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace/#css-qnames) that `height` property is not exactly what is being described either.

So, what do I do with this guy? Remove the space after the vertical bar, remove it altogether or try "`*|height`", or can he even be used on the `height` property?    Anybody?

Thanks

Comment: I think we need to actually understand what end result you are trying to achieve with this. You do not apply the namespace selector to a property, you apply it to the selector.

Comment: @anothershrubery: "I didn't write this CSS" He wouldn't know.

Comment: Well if he doesn't know what the end result should be, I'd just remove the whole line.

Comment: Thanks, anothershrubery and BoltClock. At first, I thought it was some kind of hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's both used as a namespace qualifier and a selector, neither of which are valid in this context. I'm not sure what someone intended, perhaps they wanted to comment it out. If it doesn't break everything, just remove it.