# syntax uses of the vertical bar in css

Tags: css

Is this valid css?  Can the vertical bar be used like this?

```
div{margin-left:1px !important;| margin-right:0px !important;}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Jules, I didn't write the code, its coming up as bug.  I didn't know why the coder used a pipe.

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate yes. I've done loads of reading today about it.  check out my posts [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796031/what-is-correct-syntax-for-using-vertical-bar-in-css]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use in making use of the pipe character in CSS.

Assuming you want to set the margin-left and the margin-right you can just type

```
div{margin-left:1px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}
```

as a shortened version of:

```
div {
    margin-left: 1px !important;
    margin-right:0px !important;
}
```